# Restore data of Recycler View after destroying activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

This is the situation: I have a `RecyclerView` which I load with a `List<JSONObject>` (each of the `JSONObject` has a unique identifier FYI). The rows are custom adapters, that have a couple of `ImageView` and `TextView` and a progress indicator (a `ProgressPieView`).

What I achieved:

1. Click on a `ImageView` and start a custom `AsyncTask` in the adapter (this has a couple of callbacks for the progress and the finish event).
2. When the `AsyncTask` finishes it performs a `myRecycler.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(position);` and removes the item in the `List<JSONObject>` in the callback I mentioned before inside the adapter.

This works like expected, everything seems to be working fine.

**What I want to add:**

When I go back to the previous screen and then return to the activity where I have the `RecyclerView` I want that the rows keep updating and to keep it linked with the adapter that I made before (the AsyncTasks keep working, their callbacks too).

How can I achieve this?

Can I make an adapter in the MainActivity and use it from the RecyclerViewActivity? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to return to the RecyclerView Activity and have the items already removed? Or do you want the RecyclerView to go back to its original state, then run the AsyncTasks and remove the items AGAIN?

Comment: In other words, I want my RecycleView to reflect the changes made by the AsyncTasks while it wasn't on screen. I'm making my point clear? If not, tell me, I'll try to be clearer. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to trigger the AsyncTasks, navigate away from the Activity, then have your adapter update while you're away, then when you come back to the RecyclerView, the changes are already correctly made?

Comment: Exactly that! Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, your AsyncTasks should continue to perform while their Activity is in the background. So you should be able to update the adapter in the background. So where exactly are you getting stuck? Are you running into a specific problem?

Comment: The flow is this: Activity1 (I click a button)--[I go to the second activity]-->RecyclerViewActivity(click back button)--[Go back to first activity]-->Activity one(click button)--[go to second activity]-->RecyclerViewActivity.
You are saying that I can keep running an activity on background? How? Thanks!

Comment: Each time you fire an `AsyncTask` it will continue to run even when you go to the second Activity. So in the `onPostExecute()` method, just update your adapter, and when you come back to the first Activity, notify your RecyclerView that the data set has changed.

Comment: I though about that, but I don't know how to make init the adapter and make it to "survive" even when it's activity has finished. Where should I make the adapter? Now I have it in the RecyclerViewActivity class like a private, so every time I enter, it goes null.

Comment: Okay, I've got it!! I've made the adapter `static`... Noob's error! Thanks for your help! I'll keep experimenting and then answer my own question so anyone can benefit from it :)

Comment: Now I noticed that I can't use `static` because if I want to update the adapter I can't...

Comment: You shouldn't need to make anything static. Just create your adapter as a private class member of `RecyclerViewActivity`. It will automatically be saved in the `savedInstanceState` of your Activity when you move to the next activity. So you don't have to recreate it, you just update it.

Comment: Any example of how to do that? Thank you!